# QGIS 3.6: variable functions, confusing explanation

Tags: qgis-3, function, qgis-variable

The documentation (https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html#id31) says:

> To use these functions in an expression, they should be preceded by @ character (e.g, @row_number).

map_scale is one of these variables. But if you see the example `map_get( item_variables('Map 0'), 'map_scale')`it is used **without** an `@`

Why is it in this case used without an `@`?

Comment: in this case it is necessary to read the syntax of the map_get function (map_get (map, key)): in this case map_scale represents the key

Comment: @pigreco, it's a little bit confusing.  Is there some documentation that describes the difference, when using it with or without?

Comment: to my knowledge there is no detailed documentation on these topics